# How can I use acts_as_commentable for two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller, acts-as-commentable

I want to use acts_as_commentable for two models (blog and post). I generated the comment model and added all my fields.

I created a comments_controller and in the create action I have to find blogs and posts, so for that to work I am doing something like this :-

```
def create
    if controller_name == "blogs" 
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:comment][:blog_id])
    @blog_comment = @blog.comments.new(:comment => params[:comment][:comment], :user_id => current_user.id)
    if @blog_comment.save
        flash[:success] = "Thanks for commenting"
        redirect_to :back or root_path
    else
        flash[:error] = "Comment can't be blank!"
        redirect_to :back or root_path
    end
  end


    if controller_name == "topics" 
    @post = Post.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
    @post_comment = @post.comments.new(:comment => params[:comment][:comment], :user_id => current_user.id)
    if @post_comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Thanks for commenting"
      redirect_to :back or root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Comment can't be blank!"
      redirect_to :back or root_path
    end
  end
```

I know it is pretty ugly but I don't know how to go ahead with this one, can anyone help me out?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: @ShreyasSatish I didn't see your comment before posting, you should definitely add it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the similar problem on one of my apps.

Here is what I've done:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_commentable

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end

  private
    def get_commentable
      params.each do |k, v|
        return @commentable = $1.classify.constantize.find(v) if k =~ /(.+)_id$/
      end
    end
end
```